# Convert np.array to Tensor with an extra dimention None

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have a numpy array that I convert to tensor. The shape of the array is `(50,2)`

```
h_m = np.column_stack((h_r, h_i))
```

Then I want add an extra dimension, which I want to be None, and convert it to tensor

```
h_x = h_m [None,:,:]
h = tf.convert_to_tensor(h_x,dtype=tf.float32)
```

However when I print the shape `print(np.shape(h))` it outputs `(1, 50, 2)`. How can I explicitly declared the new None dimension such that when I `print(np.shape(h))` it outputs `(?, 50, 2)`.

Comment: This kind of representation is not possible in numpy what i know of, where have you seen this before?

Comment: I'm not a `tensorflow` user, but my impression from other questions is that the `None` dimension usually represents a 'batch'  in a virtual tensor.  It's used during setup of a model.  An array may be an element of such a tensor once it's actually "used", a tensor in "eager" mode.  I imagine it's like the difference between a 'generator' and a list in basic Python.